# open slider jquery twice don't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider

I've tried to programm a slider in jQuery. This slider are centered at main page but **hidden**. When I do click on a specific image, slider turn **visible** and slider runs perfect. This slider fade out when I do click on "body" tag.

The problem: When I do click for twice on the mentioned image, the slider appear 1 second and disappear immediately.

The "solution" is refreshing web page, but I don't want to do this.

This is my HTML code:

```
<div id='slides'> 
            <ul>
                <li><img src="./img/davidMerinas.png" title="David Merinas"/></li>
                <li><img src="./img/davidMuñoz.png" title="David Muñoz"/></li>
                <li><img src="./img/enriquePalacios.png" title="Enrique Palacios"/></li>
                <li><img src="./img/fernandoHidalgo.png" title="Fenando Hidalgo"/></li>
                <li><img src="./img/franAranda.png" title="Fran Aranda"/></li>
                <li><img src="./img/ignacioAlvarez.png" title="Ignacio Alvarez"/></li>
                <li><img src="./img/iknx.png" title="IKNX"/></li>
                <li><img src="./img/javiSanchez.png" title="Javi Sanchez"/></li>
                <li><img src="./img/juanMartos.png" title="Juan Martos"/></li>
                <li><img src="./img/juanMolina.png" title="Juan Molina"/></li>
                <li><img src="./img/juanRomero.png" title="Juan Romero"/></li>
                <li><img src="./img/miguelArroyo.png" title="Miguel Arroyo"/></li>
                <li><img src="./img/miguelLopez.png" title="Miguel Lopez"/></li>
                <li><img src="./img/nicolasGarcia.png" title="Nico Garcia"/></li>
                <li><img src="./img/rafaJurado.png" title="Rafa Jurado"/></li>
                <li><img src="./img/sergioGomez.png" title="Sergio Gomez"/></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
```

This is my jQuery functions:

```
function runCarrusel(){
    $("#accordion img").click(function(){
        $("#slides").show("bind",callback);
    });
    return false;
}
function callback(){
    $("body").click(function(){
        $("#slides").fadeOut();
    });
    return false;
}

function carrusel(){
    var t = setInterval(function(){
        $("#slides ul").animate({marginLeft:-300},1000,function(){
            $(this).find("li:last").after($(this).find("li:first"));
            $(this).css({marginLeft:0});
        })
    },5000);
    return false;
}
```

I've been searching the solution, but it's impossible for me to do that. Thanks.

> The problem was the propagation of handler event to *body*. With *retun false* sentence break the event and we can do click more times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click to show the slider, the click event propagates up to the body, which hides the slider. You should stop the click event from propagating:

```
$("#accordion img").click(function(){
    $("#slides").show("bind",callback);
    return false; // This prevents the event from propagating.
});
```

Also, because you attach the click-handler to the body element in the `callback()` function, you attach a handler every time that function is called. You should just attach the handler once.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Was the propagation to body. Simple solution with a "return false;" sentence.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two separate click handlers.  Instead, inspect the target of the click event and do different things:

```
$('body').on('click', function(event) {
  var target = $(event.target);
  if (target.is('.accordion .slide')) {
    alert("show slide");
  } else {
    alert("hide slide");
  }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MLBkA/

Comment: Thanks, great aportatation and complete.